# How to import high resolution image to android studio?

Tags: android, image, android-studio, assets

So whenever I import an image as an image asset it is always blurry. When asked what type of asset is it I always select launcher. (Because thats the only way.)

I'm using the drawable as part of a selector, one image when pressed and another when not. Is there another way I can put an image in android studio?

Answer (score 2):

Use Draw 9-patch tool to create bitmap images that automatically resize to accommodate the contents of the view and the size of the screen.

You can get this tool from your Android SDK sdk/tools directory

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Note : I You want to put image according to device resolution add your image to these folders hdpi, xhdpi ,xxhdpi

Answer (score 1):

You can put images in Mipmap of all the resolution in different folder like hdpi, xhdpi ,xxhdpi and you can use it